# PHP __soapCall send received headers?

Tags: php, soap, wget

i'm trying to do a wget request to PHP and this PHP is doing a call to SOAP webservice , but i have no success. I'm sure about the webservice functionality (others apps are using this same service) and everything is running fine.

When i tried to request the WS i received the error ***"Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Client]  java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException "***.

Two questions: This is a header problem? When i do the __soapCall function, all headers from wget request are send to SOAP call?

Comment: Show us the code of the SoapCall on the PHP file.

Comment: $status = $_GET['status'];

$strServer = "http://x.x.x.x:8080/path-to-wsdl";                 
$wsdlServer = new SoapClient($strServer,array('login'=>'user','password'=>'pass','location'=>'http://path-to-wsdl'));  

$arrValues["status"] = $status;

$arrFunc = array();
$arrFunc = $wsdlServer->__soapCall("soapFunctionName",$arrValues);

Comment: The PHP is a private file, so i can't reproduce all file here, but it's working properly because others apps are using this same file.

Comment: Check in you PHP file if `$_GET` containts an entry `status` with a valid API value.

Comment: hmm, i can debug PHP to see if all all parameters is valid in API. The API expect string to all parameters.

Comment: I check the type of $status. SOAP expect "string" and PHP it also returns as "string". My bet it's about headers. I think the soap WS was expecting some headers that php are not sending